# How to increment/decrement only by one when Ray hits

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, raycasting

So, the game is to find a difference. When ray hits a collider of hidden object, it is supposed to add a score only of one and reduce a private integer differences value by one. But when the ray hits an object collider it is constantly incrementing/decrementing while the ray is hitting the collider. How can i change that? It is in the following method:

```
void Update()
    {

        camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
        Debug.DrawRay(camRay.origin, camRay.direction, Color.red, 1);

        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(camRay, out result))
            {
                /*{
                    obj = result.collider.gameObject;
                    score = score + 1;
                    differences= differences - 1;
                    score1.text = " " + score;
                    predmet.Play();                
                }*/

                if (result.collider.CompareTag("Slike") && !hitOnce)
                {
                    score +=1;
                    differences-= 1;
                    score1.text = " " + score;
                    predmet.Play();
                }
                else
                {
                    hitOnce = false;
                }

                if (differences == 0)
                {
                    WinPanel.SetActive(true);
                }
            }
        
        }       

        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first hit the object, you could remove or disable it's collider component.  This should prevent it from being hit by more Raycasts.

On first hit, something like:

```
result.collider.enabled = false;
```

Comment: Since i have 4 objects with same tag "Slike", how i can remove a collider only from one and how can i now when the first hit happened?

Comment: Well, using result.collider.enabled = false on the result of a Raycast hit should disable only the collider on the game object that was hit.  You'd have to hit each object to individually to remove each collider.  I'm not sure what you mean by "when the first hit happened."

Comment: Okay, i understand now, i will try it and let you know if it works.